# List posts in a select tag and display the_content of the selected option

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I'm trying to create a select tag with all post titles and then, when an option is selected, I need to get the_content() from that selected post by its ID and display the content below.

Esentially it would look like this:

```
<select name="menu" id="menu">
    <option value="0">Please choose a food menu:</option>
    // random IDs
    <option value="5">Food menu 1</option>
    <option value="11">Food menu 2</option>
    <option value="19">Food menu 3</option>
</select>
```

(in PHP it might be like this, at least this is all that I can do)

```
$menu_loop = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'menu',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    )
);

if ($menu_loop->have_posts()) { ?>
    <select name="menu" id="menu">
        <option value="0">Please choose a food menu:</option>

        <?php while ($menu_loop->have_posts()) : $menu_loop->the_post();
            $the_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $the_id; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
```

And then something like:

```
// get content by ID of the selected option
<?php the_content($post->ID); ?>
```

I know its much harder than what I wrote above, but I just dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

something around

```
$postid = 12;
$content_post = get_post($postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
```

Comment: Thanks, but would I have to use AJAX then to load the content when the select option is changed?